# Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=")

Tags: terraform

I have a syntax error I cannot handle. The mission was to shorten the variables (it was longer) and eventually i will need to use these vars to gather stuff such as `var.app.app1_name` from different tf files.

```
variable "apps" {
  type        = map(object({
    app_name = string
    labels = map(string)
    annotations = map(string)
  }))
  default = {
  {
      app_name = "app1_name"
      labels = {
        "name" = "stream-frontend"
        "tier" = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass" = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
      }
    },
    {
      app_name = "app2_name"
      labels = {
        "name" = "stream-backend"
        "tier" = "api"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass" = "web-backend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "internal"
      }
    },
    {
      app_name = "app3_name"
      labels = {
        "name" = "stream-database"
        "tier" = "shared"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass" = "disabled"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "disabled"
      }
    }
  }
}

variable "acl" {
  type        = map(object({
    acl_name = string
    ingress = string
    egress = string
    port = string
    protocol = string
  }))
  default = {
    {
      acl_name = "acl_frontend"
      ingress = "stream-frontend"
      egress = "0.0.0.0/0"
      port = "80"
      protocol = "TCP"
    },
    {
      acl_name = "acl_backend"
      ingress = "stream-backend"
      egress = "0.0.0.0/0"
      port = "80"
      "protocol" = "TCP"
      },
      {
        acl_name = "acl_database"
        "ingress" = "stream-database"
        "egress" = "172.17.0.0/24"
        "port" = "27017"
        "protocol" = "TCP"
      }
    }
}
```

the error:

```
Error: Missing attribute value
│
│   on NewVars.tf line 19, in variable "apps":
│    7:   default = {
│    8:   {
│    9:       app_name = "app1_name"
│   10:       labels = {
│   11:         "name" = "stream-frontend"
│   12:         "tier" = "web"
│   13:         "owner" = "product"
│   14:       }
│   15:       annotations = {
│   16:         "serviceClass" = "web-frontend"
│   17:         "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
│   18:       }
│   19:     },
│
│ Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=").
```

I've tried to :

```
variable "apps" {
  type        = list(object({
  app_name = string
  labels = map(string)
  annotations = map(string)
  }))
  
  default = [
    {
      app_name = "app1_name"
      labels = {
        "name" = "stream-frontend"
        "tier" = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I cannot access the attributes afterwards.

I need to have

`name = var.apps.app1_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what `map` type is. Maps have keys and values, i.e., they comprise what are know as [key/value pairs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#maps-objects). Now, in your case, you have defined a default value without any keys (for both variables), i.e.:

```
  default = {
  {
      app_name = "app1_name"
      labels = {
        "name" = "stream-frontend"
        "tier" = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass" = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
      }
    },
    {
      app_name = "app2_name"
      labels = {
        "name" = "stream-backend"
        "tier" = "api"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass" = "web-backend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "internal"
      }
    },
    {
      app_name = "app3_name"
      labels = {
        "name" = "stream-database"
        "tier" = "shared"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass" = "disabled"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "disabled"
      }
    }
  }
```

So to fix this for the `apps` variable, you need to change it to:

```
variable "apps" {
  type = map(object({
    app_name    = string
    labels      = map(string)
    annotations = map(string)
  }))

  default = {
    "app1_name" = {
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
      }
      app_name = "value"
      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-frontend"
        "tier"  = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
    }
    "app2_name" = {
      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
      }
      app_name = "app2_name"
      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-frontend"
        "tier"  = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The same applies in the case of the `acl` variable:

```
variable "acl" {
  type = map(object({
    acl_name = string
    ingress  = string
    egress   = string
    port     = string
    protocol = string
  }))

  default = {
    "acl_frontend" = {
      acl_name = "acl_frontend"
      egress   = "0.0.0.0/0"
      ingress  = "stream-frontend"
      port     = "80"
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment!
so if i want to make app2_name i need to open i new variable? i can't do it in the same var?
i had 3 apps and i merged the code so it will have a shorter syntax

Comment: You can, this was just an example with one key. I'll update the answer.